# Finding correct date pair and eliminate the overlapped one in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, overlap

I have a Dates like `startdate` as one column and `Enddate` as another column. I need to find eliminate Continuous date ranges in data in sQL.I need to find the overlapped items and i need to delete.I already using one code to find Overlap items.And i am giving `startdate` and `enddate` as parameter.

Code i am using to find overlap

```
Select * from #t 
where
((cast(@StartDate as datetime2)>=StartDate and cast(@EndDate as datetime2)<=EndDate)
                    OR (StartDate>= cast(@StartDate as datetime2) and EndDate<= cast(@EndDate as datetime2))
                    OR (cast(@StartDate as datetime2)>=StartDate AND cast(@StartDate as datetime2)<=EndDate)
                    OR (cast(@EndDate as datetime2)>=StartDate AND cast(@EndDate as datetime2)<=EndDate))
```

Above query is ok to find normal overlap like

| Id | Startdate | Enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 01/11/2020 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 01/03/2021 |

In above condition i will delete one data and i will keep other one

But it fails in below type of data example.When run for below type of query 1 id is overlapped with 2 and 2 is overlapped with both 1 and 3.So it show both 1 and 2 to delete.but in my case is not to delete 1 and 3.only 2 need to be deleted.since 2 is overlapped between both data and 1& 3 is already in good date periods

For example

| Id | Startdate | Enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 01/11/2020 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 01/03/2021 |
| 3 | 02/11/2020 | 05/04/2022 |

In above example we have three pair of dates and id 1 and 3 are in correct interval and 2 is overlapped between both id. I need to find overlapped one or non overlapped items. Any case is ok for me to find the result.

My Expected Result is

| Id | Startdate | Enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 01/03/2021 |

Another example is

| Id | Startdate | Enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 01/11/2020 |
| 2 | 02/11/2020 | 06/05/2022 |
| 3 | 02/11/2020 | 05/04/2022 |

Above if you see 1 and 2 is in correct date periods but id 3 is overlapped with 2 id.Now i want to find only that overlapped result and i don't need other data.

Another example is

| Id | Startdate | Enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 02/11/2020 | 05/04/2022 |

Comment: So, for the above, what are your expected results for your sample data?

Comment: I posted my expected result above

Comment: Hmm, additional examples will likely help then. I could *guess* what you want, but I think we need more than 1 example here to be clear. Otherwise I can see the goal posts being constantly moved, and that is only going to attract you downvotes from those have used their time to answer the question as it was.

Comment: I given another example for reference

Comment: So basically, you try to select everything that is not `Enddate` on the previous row plus 1 day is equal to `Startdate` of next row?

Comment: You need to state clearly when there is an overlap, what is the rule to determine which row is incorrect. And provide more example to illustrate each possible case

Comment: I given Query i used to find overlap date currently in Query

Comment: I given some information for your reference

Comment: If you have dates, why do you need to cast to datetime2? Are your parameters declared as varchar? But this seems to be a typical "gaps and islands" issue - searching on that term will find many examples.

Comment: You might find the description of the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag informative.

Comment: I doubt about your First result you posted. Is it really correct?

Comment: @Gudwlk In first set 01/01/2020 to 01/11/2020 is in correct range of date pair and it continuous with dates 02/11/2020 to 05/04/2022.if you see id 2  date pair  is overlapped between both 1 and 2 pairs.So i want to omit the correct date pairs records and need only overlapped items

Answer (score 0):

I used second set of data, But this should work for first set of data as well. But I have a doubt on your first record set expected output. If you can clear it up, i can check again,

```
  Create table OverlapData_1
  (
   id int
  , Startdate date
  , EndDate date
  )

 insert into  OverlapData_1 values(1, '01/01/2020','01/11/2020')
 insert into  OverlapData_1 values(2, '01/01/2020','01/03/2021')
 insert into  OverlapData_1 values(3, '02/11/2020','05/04/2022')

    SELECT  A.[id]
      ,A.Startdate
     ,A.EndDate FROM
      (
     SELECT
        CASE WHEN Startdate between LAG(StartDate) OVER ( order by id) and LAG(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)    THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_1]
       , CASE WHEN EndDate between LAG(StartDate) OVER ( order by id)  and  LAG(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)   THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_2]
      , CASE WHEN StartDate between LEAD(StartDate) OVER ( order by id) and  LEAD(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)  THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_3]
      , CASE WHEN EndDate between LEAD(StartDate) OVER ( order by id)  and  LEAD(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)   THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_4]
  ,*
   FROM OverlapData_1
 ) AS A 
    WHERE (A.status_1 = 1 AND A.status_2 = 1)       
      OR (A.status_1 = 1 AND A.status_4 = 1)


   
   Create table OverlapData_2
   (
     id int
    , Startdate date
   , EndDate date
    )

   insert into  OverlapData_2 values(1, '01/01/2020','01/11/2020')
   insert into  OverlapData_2 values(2, '01/01/2020','06/05/2022')
   insert into  OverlapData_2 values(3, '02/11/2020','05/04/2022')


SELECT  A.[id]
  ,A.Startdate
 ,A.EndDate FROM
(
    SELECT
       CASE WHEN Startdate between LAG(StartDate) OVER ( order by id) and LAG(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)    THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_1]
     , CASE WHEN EndDate between LAG(StartDate) OVER ( order by id)  and  LAG(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)   THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_2]
    , CASE WHEN StartDate between LEAD(StartDate) OVER ( order by id) and  LEAD(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)  THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_3]
   , CASE WHEN EndDate between LEAD(StartDate) OVER ( order by id)  and  LEAD(EndDate) OVER ( order by id)   THEN 1 else 0 end as  [status_4]
      ,*
   FROM OverlapData_2
  ) AS A 
   WHERE (A.status_1 = 1 AND A.status_2 = 1)       
     OR (A.status_1 = 1 AND A.status_4 = 1)
```

[image: Result]

[image: Result 2]

Comment: @sai krishnan can you check and let me know whether your first set expected output is correct ?

Comment: Thanks @Gudwlk.result is not coming correctly. result is `2020-01-01 | 2020-01-11`

Comment: @saikrishnan can you edit your question. I have a doubt on first result of the question!!  if it is clear, I can check again

Comment: In first set ,01/01/2020 to 01/11/2020 is in correct range of date pair and it continuous with dates 02/11/2020 to 05/04/2022.if you see id 2 date pair is overlapped between both 1 and 2 pairs.So i want to omit the correct date pairs records and need only overlapped items.
In way If you see second set 01/01/2020 to 01/11/2020 and continuous with 02/11/2020 to 06/05/2022 but id 3 is overlapped with id 2.since we wil take only last end date as main date

Comment: Ill have a try and edit the answer. the  answer I added gives correct result for set two only. right?

Comment: thanks you so much.yes it is faling in first case

Comment: @saikrishnan Hi, Sorry for the late reply. I was away.  I added some fix to the answer, Have a look and let me know. Thanks for being patient.